# JQuery element load/ready event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the element load or ready event in JQuery or Javascript. For example, consider that I am having a html page like

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="1"></div>
    <div id="2"></div>
    <div id="3"></div>
    <div id="4"></div>
    <div id="5"></div>
    <div id="6"></div>
</body>
```

Here I should get notified when div with id 3 get's ready. This event should get fired before document.ready event as the element gets ready before that.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can't attach a `load` event listener to a `div` (only to `window`, `body`, scripts, images and iframes), but you can insert your script after the third `div`:

```
<body>
    <div id="1"></div>
    <div id="2"></div>
    <div id="3"></div>
    <script>doSomething()</script>
    <div id="4"></div>
    <div id="5"></div>
    <div id="6"></div>
</body>
```

Of course, this doesn't guarantee that all elements inside the `div` (images etc.) have finished loading.

Comment: Yup Viktor.I agreed.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys. The issue is that, I don't have any control on the html side (I can't inject script after div 3). I can have my own javascript, which will be imported in the head. Here I am having only element id (In this case 3 as my div id), I want to inject my element immediately after the div 3 is available and I can't wait till the dom gets ready.

Comment: @Nikhil Hmm, you could poll the element in an interval, waiting for it to become available. `var pollElementInterval = window.setInterval(function() { var $elem = $('#3'); if ($elem.length) { $elem.append('<div id="element-to-inject">'); window.clearInterval(pollElementInterval); } }, 100);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this...

JavaScript :

```
<script>
function myfunction(){
//my stuff;
}
</script>
```

HTML :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="1">A</div>
    <div id="2">B</div>
    <div id="3" >C</div>
    <script>myfunction()</script>
    <div id="4">D</div>
    <div id="5">E</div>
    <div id="6">F</div>
</body>
</html>
```